# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main' in Flask application deployed on gcloud

Tags: python, flask, deployment, gcloud, flask-socketio

I am getting the error  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'. I have a flask application deployed on gcloud.

The build was successful on gcloud. The url is given in the logs. But when i invoke the url, the logs shows the below error

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'

and i get 502 Bad gateway error

Any help is much appreciated.

Below are the respective files.

**requirements.txt**

flask
flask_socketio
flask_caching
flask_cors
gunicorn

**cloudbuild.yaml**

## Install dependencies

- name: 'python:3.11'
  entrypoint: 'pip'
  args: ['install', '-r', 'requirements.txt']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  entrypoint: '/bin/sh'

  args:

  - '-c'
  - |
    gcloud app deploy app.yaml
    timeout: 1600s

**app.yaml**

runtime: python311

handlers:

- url: /static
  static_dir: static
- url: /.*
  script: |
  gunicorn -b :8081   app:app

** app.py **

```
`from flask import Flask
import sys
import os
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

    
# Create a Flask application
app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

# Define a route for the homepage
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return 'Hello, World! This is the homepage.'

# Define a route for a custom endpoint
@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return 'This is the about page.'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    host = os.environ.get("HOST", "0.0.0.0")
    socketio.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8081)`
```

I have tried building and deploying on gcloud and I expect to see my flask application running. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: in case you haven't seen it, I wanted to make sure you saw [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/building-app/deploying-web-service) about deploying a web service to App Engine - it includes a link to a sample where you can compare the sample code with your code. I suspect that it might be the app.yaml that isn't quite right, or it may be that your script is named `app.py` and it's expecting `main.py`.